# python dictionary elements overwriting themselves

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to do a calculation and keep track of the running changes in a dict:

```
import numpy as np

d = dict()
arr_run = np.zeros([10,5])
for i in range(10):
    arr = np.random.randn(10-i,5)
    arr_run[i:,:] = arr
    d['bump'+str(i)] = arr_run
```

However, the previous elements in d update automatically as soon as `arr_run[i:,:] = arr` runs.

Meaning that all elements show the latest `arr_run` as opposed to preserving its previous states.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to take a snapshot of arr_run?

Comment: @Max yes- that's exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @JohnColeman Forgive my ignorance but I don't know what that means.

Comment: `arr_run = np.zeros([10,5])` creates 1 array, and you never have any more than 1 array that you are repeatedly assigning as value to the dictionary. All dictionary keys point to exactly the same array. If you want to store *copies* in each iteration you would have to make the copies explicitly.

Comment: @RealRageDontQuit I delete my answer as their is already better answer. Mine has problem as you mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `copy` of the array at every iteration.

```
d = dict()
arr_run = np.zeros([10,5])
for i in range(10):
    arr = np.random.randn(10-i,5)
    arr_run[i:,:] = arr
    d['bump'+str(i)] = np.copy(arr_run)
```

Comment: but wouldn't that delete the previous entries as you are reset the dictionary back to empty?

Comment: bingo - thank you! I was trying to do arr_run.deepcopy() but it wasn't working.

Comment: @RealRageDontQuit - The [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) say this is the preferred method for creating an array copy! :)